# How can I temporarily short-circuit two adjacent poles on a circuit board cheaply?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, short-circuit, hardware

On the image below I need to short circuit GP100 to enter flash mode on an esp-chip. I can't afford a soldering iron atm (and also don't know how to solder). I'm currently trying to do it by holding small screwdriver between the pins. I need to hold down a button and plugin a USB at the same time, so it's kind of tricky. Is there any other good trade-trick for doing this?

[image]

Comment: PGIO0. Do you mean GP100. Note difference between 'I' / '1' and 'O' / '0'. Edit your question.

Comment: Are you looking for a temporal solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too poor to buy a $10 soldering iron?

You need something which can be held with one hand yet make contact on the two pads at once, and it also needs pointy bits to punch through the oxidation.

Check your medicine cabinet for a set of tweezers:

[image]

Comment: downvote for sexism, otherwise would be a good answer

Comment: @pericynthion I've corrected the issue.

Comment: Some of us learned the virtues of tweezers from both parents at once ;)